# How to access prop in child of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have three component say A, B, C.
I need to pass the style from A component to C component as a prop.
In A component I have mention the

```
    const customeStyle : Istyle
    {
    overFlow: 'auto'
    }
```

Now I need to get this property in component C as a IStyle.

In A component I am passing as a

```
    <A {...this.props.customStyle} />
```

I have created the interface

```
   interface IProps
   {
    style : IStyle
   }
```

In B Component

```
   Class B extends React.Component<IProps>

   <C { ...this.props.customStyle}
```

In C componet

```
          Class C extends React.Component<IProps>
```

How to get props value as a Istyle , because i need to give dynamically overflow property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what you're passing down. When you spread an object, you use its keys, i.e. you're not passing the style as a prop but rather its properties.

```
<A {...this.props.customStyle} />
```

is the same as

```
<A overFlow="auto" />
```

Comment: There can be more property like minWidth, maxwidth, so that's why I need interface which contains iStyle as a interface. So In Main component A  want to pass all property and want to access in component C. so that i can access this interface and then simply access iStyle

Comment: If we are passing props as overflow then it will give typescript error that type not defined so we need to use interface.